# Bootstrap don't let me center divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm using mvc5 with razor viewengine and bootstrap 
I want  became some images centered , when I use Boostrap.css center not working but when I delete bootstrap.css it works fine . I used bootsrtap `text center class` but it doesn't work too :/
http://jsfiddle.net/9h5rvgLc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.img-responsive{ margin:0px auto}` may it works for you

Comment: do you know I myself  tested it But it doesn't work , but it worked , shame on me , thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is an another way to do that:

Include **class="center-block"** in the image as follows:

```
<img .. class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" />
```

Check Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9h5rvgLc/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display: block; margin: 10px auto` to the `style` attribute. That will center the `div` the image. I have updated the jsfiddle for demo, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9h5rvgLc/1/).

```
<div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img style="display: block; margin: 10px auto; width:450px ; height:390px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h3 class="h">@item.GoodTitle</h3>
    <h5 class="h">@item.GoodSubText</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ps. Would also change the `height` from `height: 390px` to `height: auto` to avoid the image stretching.

Answer (score 1):

Change your image tag to this:

```
<img style="width:450px ; height:390px; display: inline" class="img-responsive" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg" />
```

Notice I added: `display: inline`